# FileNotFoundError: Couldn't find any class folder in /content/data

Tags: машинное-обучение, нейронные-сети, pytorch

Пытаюсь передать в ImageFolder путь до папки с картинками,

```
imgset = datasets.ImageFolder(args.path)
```

который беру из командной строки.
Получаю ошибку, указанную в заголовке. Путь выглядит как root/dataset (делаю генератор, поэтому класс изображений один). Может быть, ImageFolder на вход должна получать список путей до каждой фотографии? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Может быть. А что по этому поводу говорит документация?

Comment: Документация ничего не говорит про одноклассовые выборки, а указывает лишь тот факт, что в пути должны указываться классы. Но я делаю генератор, и, соответственно, выборка у меня одноклассовая.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартный загрузчик ожидает на вход  директорию вида root/data, то есть для одноклассовых манипуляций необходимо назвать первую папку root, а вторую папку, которая будет находиться в папке root, наименованием выборки (например, data). И именно в data будут находиться изображения, с которыми вы хотите работать.
То есть путь должен быть вида root/data. root, это важно!!!!!